# Cannot save log files when using a ROS enabled plugin

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am getting the following warning when shutting down Gazebo (1.8.0) and using ROS enabled plugins in the code, and because of this warning, the log file is not saved:

```
Warning [gazebo_main.cc:57] escalating to SIGKILL on server
```

After removing the ROS parts from the plugin, the shutdown works fine, and the log file is also saved.
The plugin is similar to the one from the [tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/ros_enabled_model_plugin).

The warning appears even if I don't use a ROS subscriber. I also tried `rosnode->shutdown()` at a moment in the code, but without success.

Thanks,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2850/cannot-save-log-files-when-using-a-ros-enabled-plugin/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2013-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try running `gzlog stop` and waiting for Gazebo to come unpaused (it'll pause while flushing the log) before shutting down.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-05-17**:
Thanks, it worked